# Trigger a jquery function from an URL -- modify function?

Tags: jquery, function, url, menu

I have a working pullup menu which I am having trouble modifying. I need to be able to pass a value into the page through the URL and use that to open the selected menu. I have this working in **ServiceNow** (the reason for the $j) using **jquery-1.8.2.min**. I have the following code in an include file:

```
(function($j){
/*------------------------------------------*/

/*               JavaScript On              */

/*------------------------------------------*/
$j("html").addClass("jsOn");

/*------------------------------------------*/

/*                Mouse Over                */

/*------------------------------------------*/
$j(document).ready(function() {
    var hover = ".PullUpMenu a, #Contents h2 a, #Contents h3 a, #SliderArea a, #Release a";
    $j(hover).on("mouseover focus", function() {
        $j(this).find("img").stop().animate({opacity:"0.7"}, 200);
    }).on("mouseout blur", function() {
        $j(this).find("img").stop().animate({opacity:"1"}, 200);
    });
});

/*------------------------------------------*/

/*                User Agent                */

/*------------------------------------------*/
var nut = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var sp = nut.indexOf("iphone") != -1 || nut.indexOf("ipad") != -1 || nut.indexOf("ipod") != -1 || nut.indexOf("android") != -1;
var ie8 = nut.indexOf("msie 8") != -1;

/*------------------------------------------*/

/*                Pull Up Menu              */

/*------------------------------------------*/
$j(document).ready(function() {
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
        $j("#PullUpMenu"+i+" a").addClass("pum"+i);
    }
    $j(".GlobalNav a").addClass("gn");
    var openMenu = function(open, n) {
        if(open) {
            $j(".PullUpMenu").eq(n).css({display:"block"}).stop().animate({top:"-343px", height:"350px"}, 300, "swing");
            $j(".gn").removeClass("current").eq(n).addClass("current");
        } else {
            $j(".PullUpMenu").eq(n).stop().animate({top:"7px", height:"10px"}, 300, "swing", function() {$j(this).css({display:"none"});});
            $j(".gn").eq(n).removeClass("current");
        }
    }
    if(!sp) {
        var gn = function(s) {
            if($j(s).hasClass("gn")) {
                return $j(".gn").index(s);
            } else if($j(s).hasClass("pum1") || $j(s).hasClass("pum2") || $j(s).hasClass("pum3") || $j(s).hasClass("pum4")){
                return $j(s).attr("class").charAt(3)-1;
            } else {
                return $j(".PullUpMenu").index(s);
            }
        }
        $j(".PullUpMenu, .gn, .menu").on("mouseover focusin", function() {
            openMenu(1, gn(this));
        }).on("mouseout focusout", function() {
            openMenu(0, gn(this));
        });
        //$j(".gn").on("click", function() {return false;});
    } else {
        var open = [];
        $j(".gn").on("click", function() {
            var n = $j(".gn").index(this);
            $j(".gn").each(function(e) {
                if(e == n) {
                    var op = (open[n]) ? 0 : 1;
                    openMenu(op, n);
                    open[n] = op;
                } else {
                    openMenu(0, e);
                    open[e] = 0;
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
});

/*------------------------------------------*/

/*                Topics Tab                */

/*------------------------------------------*/
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j("#TopicsSet ul#TopicsBtn a").on("click", function() {
        var tabNum = $j("#TopicsSet ul#TopicsBtn a").index(this);
        $j("#TopicsSet ul#TopicsBtn a").removeClass("current").eq(tabNum).addClass("current");
        $j("#TopicsSet div").css({display:"none"}).eq(tabNum).css({display:"block"});
        return false;
    });
});

/*------------------------------------------*/

/*                Slide Banner              */

/*------------------------------------------*/
$j(document).ready(function() {
    var bnrMax = $j("#SliderArea ul li").length;
    if(bnrMax <= 4) return false;
    var slideInterval = 5000;
    var flag = 0;
    var tid;
    var sbs = 0;
    var sd = '<div id="SlideButton">';
    sd += '<div id="SlideButtonLeft"><a href="#"><img src="/image/h5_en/top/button_slide_left.gif" alt="Previous" width="30" height="60" /></a></div>';
    sd += '<div id="SlideButtonStop"><a href="#"><img src="/image/h5_en/top/button_slide_stop_off.gif" alt="Stop" width="30" height="60" /></a></div>';
    sd += '<div id="SlideButtonRight"><a href="#"><img src="/image/h5_en/top/button_slide_right.gif" alt="Next" width="30" height="60" /></a></div>';
    sd += '</div>';
    $j(sd).appendTo("#RotationBanner");
    $j("#SlideButton").css({display: "block"});
    var autoslide = function() {
        tid = setTimeout(function() {
            slide(0);
        }, slideInterval);}
    var slide = function(lr) {
        flag = 1;
        if(lr) {
            $j("#SliderArea ul li:last").insertBefore("#SliderArea ul li:first");
            $j("#SliderArea ul").css({left:"-245px"}).animate({left:"0px"}, 400, "swing", function() {
                flag = 0;
                if(!sbs) autoslide();
            });
        } else {
            $j("#SliderArea ul").animate({left:"-245px"}, 400, "swing", function() {
                $j("#SliderArea ul li:first").appendTo(this);
                $j(this).css({left:"0"});
                flag = 0;
                if(!sbs) autoslide();
            });
        }
    }
    $j("#SlideButtonLeft a, #SlideButtonRight a").on("click", function() {
        $j(this).blur();
        if(flag) return false;
        clearTimeout(tid);
        var button = ($j(this).parent().attr("id") == "SlideButtonLeft") ? 1 : 0;
        slide(button);
        return false;
    });
    $j("#SlideButtonStop a").on("click", function() {
        $j(this).blur();
        var src = $j(this).find("img").attr("src");
        if(!sbs) {
            sbs = 1;
            $j(this).find("img").attr("src", src.replace("_off.", "_on."));
            clearTimeout(tid);
        } else {
            sbs = 0;
            $j(this).find("img").attr("src", src.replace("_on.", "_off."));
            autoslide();
        }
        return false;
    });
    autoslide();
});

/*------------------------------------------*/
/*                for IE8                   */
/*------------------------------------------*/
$j(document).ready(function() {
    if(!ie8) return false;
    var brandingIE8 = function() {
        var w = $(window).width();
        var hw = (w>965) ? Math.floor(w/2)+"px" : "482px";
        $j("#BrandingImgStyle").css({left:hw});
    }
    brandingIE8();
    $j(window).on("resize", brandingIE8);
});
})(jQuery);
```

This is the code with the HTML and file calls:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<j:jelly trim="false" xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:g="glide" xmlns:j2="null" xmlns:g2="null">
    <g:requires name="scripts/lib/jquery_includes.js"/>
    <g:include_script src="corporate.jsdbx"/>
    <g:include_script src="bjqs-1.3.min.jsdbx"/>
    <script class="secret-source">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($j) {          
        $j('#banner-slide').bjqs({
        animtype      : 'slide',
        height        : 300,
        width         : 960,
        responsive    : true,
        randomstart   : false
        });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        body {behavior: url("csshover3.htc");}
        #menu li .drop {background:url("img/drop.gif") no-repeat right 8px; 
    </style>

    <table id="_tblcontent" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="960px">
        <!--Header Menu and Scroller Image-->
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <!--BrandingAreaContainer-->
                <div id="BrandingAreaContainer">
                    <!--BrandingArea-->
                    <div id="BrandingArea">                             
                        <table id="_content1" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
                            <tr>
                                <td id="_img-slider" width="100%" height="300px" align="center">
                                    <div id="banner-slide">
                                        <!-- start Basic Jquery Slider -->
                                        <ul class="bjqs">
                                            <li><img src="fanatical.pngx" title="" /></li>
                                            <li><img src="results.jpgx" title="" /></li>
                                            <li><img src="Greatness.jpgx" title="" /></li>
                                            <li><img src="passion.jpgx" title="" /></li>
                                            <li><img src="transparency.jpgx" title="" /></li>
                                            <li><img src="friendsfamily.jpgx" title="" /></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <!-- end Basic jQuery Slider -->
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <!--/BrandingArea-->

                    <!--GlobalNavContainer-->
                    <div id="GlobalNavContainer">
                        <!--GlobalNav-->
                        <div id="GlobalNav">
                            <div id="GlobalNav1" class="GlobalNav"> 
                                <a id="Nav1" href="#">
                                    <img src="nav1.gifx" alt="Service Desk" height="127" width="240" /> 
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <!--PullUpMenu1-->
                            <div id="PullUpMenu1" class="PullUpMenu">
                                <h2 class="ImageStyle">
                                    <a href="#">Service Desk ></a>
                                </h2>
                                <ul id="menu" class="ClearFix">
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="drop" href="#">Computers and Hardware</a>
                                        <div class="dropdown_4columns"><!-- Begin 4 column container -->
                                            <div class="col_1">
                                                <ul class="greybox">
                                                    <li><a href="e6430.do">HP z6430</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="e6530.do">HP z6530</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="e6330.do">z6330 UK</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="e6430u_standard.do">HP z430u US</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col_1">
                                                <ul class="greybox">
                                                    <li><a href="6430u">HP 7430u</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="mac_13_pro.do">13" MacBook Pro</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="mac_15_pro.do">15" MacBook  Pro</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="mac_15_retina.do">15" Macbook Pro Retina</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col_1">
                                                <ul class="greybox">
                                                    <li><a href="dell_optiplex.do">Dell Optiplex</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="sd_order_mac_mini.do">Mac Mini</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="sd_order_desk_phone.do">Desk Phone</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="sd_order_printer.do">Printer</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col_1">
                                                <ul class="greybox">
                                                    <li><a href="smobile_phone.do">Mobile Device</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="accessories.do">Accessories</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div><!-- End 4 column container -->
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="drop" href="#">Software and Applications</a>
                                        <div class="dropdown_3columns"><!-- Begin 3 column container -->
                                            <div class="col_1">
                                                <ul class="greybox">
                                                    <li><a href="ms_office.do">Microsoft Office</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="ms_sharepoint.do">Microsoft Sharepoint</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="adobe_other.do">Other Adobe</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col_1">
                                                <ul class="greybox">
                                                    <li><a href="ms_visio.do">Microsoft Visio</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="ms_other.do">Microsoft Other</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col_1">
                                                <ul class="greybox">
                                                    <li><a href="ms_project.do">Microsoft Project</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="adobe_acrobat.do">Adobe Acrobat</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div><!-- End 3 column container -->
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <!--/PullUpMenu1-->

                            <div id="GlobalNav2" class="GlobalNav">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img src="nav2.gifx" alt="Services" height="127" width="240" />
                                </a>
                            </div>                                  
                            <!--PullUpMenu2-->
                            <div id="PullUpMenu2" class="PullUpMenu" style="display: none; overflow: hidden; top: 7px; height: 10px;">
                                <h2 class="ImageStyle">
                                    <a href="#">Services ></a>
                                </h2>
                                <ul id="menu" class="ClearFix">
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="drop" href="#">Change Management</a>
                                        <div class="dropdown_1column"><!-- Begin 1 column container -->
                                            <div class="col_1">
                                                <ul class="greybox">
                                                    <li><a href="changes.do">View Open Change Requests</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="changes.do">View Closed Change Requests</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="calender.do">View Change Request Calendar</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="drop" href="#">Incident Management</a>
                                        <div class="dropdown_1column"><!-- Begin 1 column container -->
                                            <div class="col_1">
                                                <ul class="greybox">
                                                    <li><a href="incidents.do">View Open Incidents</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="incidents.do">View Closed Incidents</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">View Dashboards</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="drop" href="#">Deployments</a>
                                        <div class="dropdown_2columns"><!-- Begin 2 column container -->
                                            <div class="col_1">
                                                <ul class="greybox">
                                                    <li><a href="deployment.do">Create Deployment Request</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="requests.do">All Open Deployments</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col_1">
                                                <ul class="greybox">
                                                    <li><a href="requests.do">My Open Deployments</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="requests.do">My Closed Deployments</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div><!-- End 2 column container -->
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <!--/PullUpMenu2-->

                            <div id="GlobalNav3" class="GlobalNav">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img src="nav3.gifx" alt="Systems" height="127" width="240" />
                                </a>
                            </div>                                  
                            <!--PullUpMenu3-->
                            <div id="PullUpMenu3" class="PullUpMenu" style="display: none; overflow: hidden; top: 7px; height: 10px;">
                                <h2 class="ImageStyle">
                                    <a href="#">Systems ></a>
                                </h2>

                                <ul id="menu" class="ClearFix">
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="drop" href="#">Post</a>
                                        <div class="dropdown_4columns"><!-- Begin 4 column container -->
                                            <div class="col_1">
                                                <ul class="greybox">
                                                    <li><a href="access.do">Access and Permissions</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="price_change.do">Price Change Request</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col_1">
                                                <ul class="greybox">
                                                    <li><a href="analysis.do">Analysis Request</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="issue.do">Report an Issue</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col_1">
                                                <ul class="greybox">
                                                    <li><a href="operational.do">Operational Request</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col_1">
                                                <ul class="greybox">
                                                    <li><a href="env.do">Environment Deployment Request</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div><!-- End 4 column container -->
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <!--/PullUpMenu3-->
                            <div id="GlobalNav4" class="GlobalNav">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img src="nav4.gifx" alt="My Corner" height="127" width="240" />
                                </a>
                            </div>                                  
                            <!--PullUpMenu4-->
                            <div id="PullUpMenu4" class="PullUpMenu" style="display: none; overflow: hidden; top: 7px; height: 10px;">
                                <h2 class="ImageStyle">
                                    <a href="#">My Corner ></a>
                                </h2>

                                <ul id="menu" class="ClearFix">
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="drop" href="#">Human Resources</a>
                                        <div class="dropdown_1column"><!-- Begin 1 column container -->
                                            <div class="col_1">
                                                <ul class="greybox">
                                                    <li><a href="new.do">Create an HR Request</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="requests.do">My Requests</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="requests.do">My Closed Requests</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>

                                    <li>
                                        <a class="drop" href="#">Payroll</a>
                                        <div class="dropdown_1column"><!-- Begin 1 column container -->
                                            <div class="col_1">
                                                <ul class="greybox">
                                                    <li><a href="new.do">Create a Payroll Request</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="requests.do">My Requests</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="requests.do">My Closed Requests</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <!--/PullUpMenu-->
                        </div>
                        <!--/GlobalNav-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/GlobalNavContainer-->
                </div>
                <!--/BrandingAreaContainer-->
            </td>
        </tr>                   
        <!--/Header Menu and Scroller Image-->
    </table>                                                            
</j:jelly>
```

There are two actions I need to come out with: 1) to be able to pass a value from an URL to the code, and 2) to have that value show the selected pullup ment. I tried multiple ways of just calling the function on the page to even get the action with no success. I'm a relatively new jquery user, so it's taking some time to get up to speed.

This was some of the last code I tried, which failed miserably:

```
<script class="pick-me">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($j) { 
            $j(openMenu(1, gn('a#Nav1')););         
    });
</script>
```

and

```
<script class="pick-me">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($j) { 
            $j(('a#Nav1').openMenu(1, this););         
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the library you are using for the menu along with a more concrete example of the exact functionality you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Edited to add the missing information and the full code. Previously I was only including a snippet of the code relevant to the action.

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining `$j` as jQuery in your script.

You will want to wrap everything in an [immediately invoked function expression](http://stage.learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/functions/#immediately-invoked-function-expression) like so:

```
(function ($j) {
    $j(document).ready(function () {

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            $j("#PullUpMenu" + i + " a").addClass("pum" + i);

        }

        $j(".GlobalNav a").addClass("gn");



        var openMenu = function (open, n) {

            if (open) {

                $j(".PullUpMenu").eq(n).css({
                    display: "block"
                }).stop().animate({
                    top: "-343px",
                    height: "350px"
                }, 300, "swing");

                $j(".gn").removeClass("current").eq(n).addClass("current");

            } else {

                $j(".PullUpMenu").eq(n).stop().animate({
                    top: "7px",
                    height: "10px"
                }, 300, "swing", function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        display: "none"
                    });
                });

                $j(".gn").eq(n).removeClass("current");

            }

        }

        if (!sp) {
            var gn = function (s) {

                if ($j(s).hasClass("gn")) {

                    return $j(".gn").index(s);

                } else if ($j(s).hasClass("pum1") || $j(s).hasClass("pum2") || $j(s).hasClass("pum3") || $j(s).hasClass("pum4")) {

                    return $j(s).attr("class").charAt(3) - 1;

                } else {

                    return $j(".PullUpMenu").index(s);

                }

            }

            $j(".PullUpMenu, .gn").on("mouseover focusin", function () {

                openMenu(1, gn(this));

            }).on("mouseout focusout", function () {

                openMenu(0, gn(this));

            });

            //$j(".gn").on("click", function() {return false;});

        } else {
            var open = [];

            $j(".gn").on("click", function () {

                var n = $j(".gn").index(this);

                $j(".gn").each(function (e) {

                    if (e == n) {

                        var op = (open[n]) ? 0 : 1;

                        openMenu(op, n);

                        open[n] = op;

                    } else {

                        openMenu(0, e);

                        open[e] = 0;

                    }

                });

                return false;

            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Note the `(function($j) { //your code })(jQuery);`

Comment: Argh, your over-spacing hurts my eyes

Comment: Nothing is over-indented. The line spacing is from OP.

Comment: I'll take back my monitor to the store than!

Comment: Just added the HTML part as well

Answer (score 0):

I worked with a teammate to resolve this, but I still need to add in a little cross-browser functionality.

On the sub pages, we added the following code to index the navigation, which is in the same order:

```
  $j(document).ready(function () {
$j(".cms_menu_dropdown_link").on("click", function() {
  localStorage.setItem("menu_index", $j(this).parent().index());
});
```

and in the file, within the Pullup menu, we added:

```
    if(localStorage.getItem("menu_index") !== null) {
    openMenu(1,localStorage.getItem("menu_index"))
}
```

This is working great in Chrome, but I need to tweak it for other browsers I believe.